# Выбрать значение из одного из двух столбцов при выполнении условия по двум другим столбцам

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, сравнение

Имеется следующий исходный датафрейм со следующими столбцами:

```
     Manual_grade  Date_manual_grade    Auto_grade Date_auto_grade
0    6.0           2018-05-30 15:53:00    7.0     2018-05-30 15:52:00
1    6.0           2017-09-27 10:02:00    5.0     2017-12-21 22:14:00
2    6.0           2018-06-28 10:57:00    9.0     2018-08-06 15:11:00
3    5.0           2018-06-26 15:46:00    5.0     2018-06-26 15:42:00
4    5.0           2014-11-12 00:00:00    6.0     2018-07-31 22:34:00
5    6.0           2018-04-12 13:20:00    5.0     2018-04-12 13:18:00
6    5.0           2015-11-12 00:00:00    NaN     2016-03-22 09:52:00
7    6.0           2016-05-24 00:00:00    6.0     2018-08-29 15:48:00
8    7.0           2017-12-19 14:29:00    9.0     2018-01-12 14:31:00
9    NaN            NaT                   5.0     2018-08-11 10:16:00
10   NaN            NaT                   6.0     2018-10-22 13:55:00
```

Нужно сделать так,чтобы в новый дополнительный столбец записывался Grade, который самый последний по дате, т.е что-то вроде этого:

```
if df[Date_manual_grade] > df[Date_auto_grade]:
    df[Current_grade] = df[Manual_grade]
else:
    df[Auto_grade]
```

чтобы на выходе было следующее:

```
     Manual_grade  Date_manual_grade    Auto_grade Date_auto_grade      Current
0    6.0           2018-05-30 15:53:00    7.0     2018-05-30 15:52:00      6.0
1    6.0           2017-09-27 10:02:00    5.0     2017-12-21 22:14:00      5.0
2    6.0           2018-06-28 10:57:00    9.0     2018-08-06 15:11:00      9.0
3    5.0           2018-06-26 15:46:00    5.0     2018-06-26 15:42:00      5.0
4    5.0           2014-11-12 00:00:00    6.0     2018-07-31 22:34:00      5.0
5    6.0           2018-04-12 13:20:00    5.0     2018-04-12 13:18:00      6.0
6    5.0           2015-11-12 00:00:00    NaN     2016-03-22 09:52:00      5.0
7    6.0           2016-05-24 00:00:00    6.0     2018-08-29 15:48:00      6.0
8    7.0           2017-12-19 14:29:00    9.0     2018-01-12 14:31:00      9.0
9    NaN            NaT                   5.0     2018-08-11 10:16:00      5.0
10   NaN            NaT                   6.0     2018-10-22 13:55:00      6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция [numpy.where](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) позволяет реализовать `if ... else ...` логику в *векторизированном* виде:

```
df['Current'] = np.where(df['Date_manual_grade'] > df['Date_auto_grade'],
                         df['Manual_grade'].combine_first(df['Auto_grade']),
                         df['Auto_grade'].combine_first(df['Manual_grade']))
```

PS [Series.combine_first(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) возвращает значения из Series если значение не является `NaN`/`NaT`, в противном случае выбирается соответствующее значение из `other`.

результат:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
    Manual_grade   Date_manual_grade  Auto_grade     Date_auto_grade  Current
0            6.0 2018-05-30 15:53:00         7.0 2018-05-30 15:52:00      6.0
1            6.0 2017-09-27 10:02:00         5.0 2017-12-21 22:14:00      5.0
2            6.0 2018-06-28 10:57:00         9.0 2018-08-06 15:11:00      9.0
3            5.0 2018-06-26 15:46:00         5.0 2018-06-26 15:42:00      5.0
4            5.0 2014-11-12 00:00:00         6.0 2018-07-31 22:34:00      6.0
5            6.0 2018-04-12 13:20:00         5.0 2018-04-12 13:18:00      6.0
6            5.0 2015-11-12 00:00:00         NaN 2016-03-22 09:52:00      5.0
7            6.0 2016-05-24 00:00:00         6.0 2018-08-29 15:48:00      6.0
8            7.0 2017-12-19 14:29:00         9.0 2018-01-12 14:31:00      9.0
9            NaN                 NaT         5.0 2018-08-11 10:16:00      5.0
10           NaN                 NaT         6.0 2018-10-22 13:55:00      6.0
```

Comment: спасибо, а как поступить, со значение NaN в новом столбце? Там в 6-й строке условие совпало, но Auto_grade отсуствует, можно как-то просписать доп условие, чтобы в таком случае проставлялось значение из Manual_grade?

Comment: @Pavel, можно, дополнил ответ...

Comment: Спасибо, большое!!!!

Comment: @Pavel, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)